# Query Optimisation: SUMIF and CASE WHEN

Tags: sql, optimization, google-bigquery, subquery, case

I am writing a query to pull the number of rewarded ads. To do so, I have to sum "rewarded_ad" events from event_name. Then, I am cleaning up null values in a second statement. So currently, my query includes a subquery. However, is there a way to do this without utilising a subquery? I am looking to optimise this process.

My subquery includes:

```
SUM(IF(LOWER(event_name)= 'rewarded_ad', 1,0)) AS rewarded_ad
```

The outside query includes:

```
CASE WHEN rewarded_ad IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE rewarded_ad END AS rv_count
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace:

```
SUM(IF(LOWER(event_name)= 'rewarded_ad', 1,0)) AS rewarded_ad
```

with:

```
COUNTIF(LOWER(event_name) = 'rewarded_ad') AS rewarded_ad
```

This should never return `NULL` because `COUNT()` never returns `NULL`.  So, this should answer your question with no subquery.  But a `NULL` values can appear if the subquery returns no rows.  To handle that, use `COALESCE()`:

```
COALESCE(COUNTIF(LOWER(event_name) = 'rewarded_ad'), 0) AS rewarded_ad
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe IFNULL?

```
IFNULL(SUM(IF(LOWER(event_name)= 'rewarded_ad', 1,0)), 0) AS rv_count
```